# finding top k largest keys in a dictionary python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a dictionary:

```
{key1:value1........... keyn:valuen}
```

So lets say I want to write a function

```
def return_top_k(dictionary, k):

    return list_of_keys_sorted
```

What is the most efficient way (in terms of big O) to get the keys which have the top k values (maintaining the order i.e the highest value key is present in the beginning.. and so on.)

Comment: When talking about dictionaries using `k` for a count is confusing because it often stands for 'key'.  Use `n` instead.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`O(n log k)`:

```
import heapq

k_keys_sorted = heapq.nlargest(k, dictionary)
```

You could use `key` keyword parameter to specify what should be used as a sorting key e.g.:

```
k_keys_sorted_by_values = heapq.nlargest(k, dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
```

Comment: I think the OP is actually asking for something like `heapq.nlargest(k, dictionary, key=dictionary.__getitem__)`: dictionary keys ordered by their values.

Comment: Note, that this a result for sorting keys

Comment: @Dougal: `list_of_keys_sorted` suggests otherwise

Comment: Hmm, true. The word "value" is confusing; either one might be right. :)

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch01s04.html

Answer (score 8):

```
return sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)[:10]
```

Should be at worst `O(NlogN)` (although `heapq` proposed by others is probably better) ...

It *might* also make sense to use a `Counter` instead of a regular dictionary.  In that case, the `most_common` method will do (approximately) what you want (`dictionary.most_common(10)`), but only if it makes sense to use a `Counter` in your API.

Comment: This is perfect.  I'll add that if the dictionary happens to a dictionary of counts, `collections.Counter` would be the right data structure.  Then the solution would be `[k for k, v in counts.most_common(10)]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
portfolio = [
   {'name': 'IBM', 'shares': 100, 'price': 91.1},
   {'name': 'AAPL', 'shares': 50, 'price': 543.22},
   {'name': 'FB', 'shares': 200, 'price': 21.09},
   {'name': 'HPQ', 'shares': 35, 'price': 31.75},
   {'name': 'YHOO', 'shares': 45, 'price': 16.35},
   {'name': 'ACME', 'shares': 75, 'price': 115.65}
]

cheap = heapq.nsmallest(3, portfolio, key=lambda s: s['price'])
expensive = heapq.nlargest(3, portfolio, key=lambda s: s['price'])
```

Answer (score 3):

For top-3 step by step:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dct = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
>>> sorted(dct.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('e', 5), ('d', 4), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
>>> map(itemgetter(0), sorted(dct.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
>>> map(itemgetter(0), sorted(dct.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))[:3]
['e', 'd', 'c']
```

Or using `heapq` module

```
>>> import heapq
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, dct.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
[('e', 5), ('d', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>> map(itemgetter(0), _)
['e', 'd', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

In code

```
dct = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
k = 3
print sorted(dct.keys(), reverse=True)[:k]
```

If you also need values:

```
print sorted(dct.items(), reverse=True)[:k]
```

Or if you would want to use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(sorted(dct.items(), reverse=True))
print d.keys()[:k]
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you want top K frequent Elements to be printed from the Dictionary; you have to use heapq.nlargest funtcion.

Here is the example for the same:

```
return heapq.nlargest(k,count.keys(), key = count.get)
```

Here, k is the number that helps us find out elements which are repeated in a dictionary k times or more than k times.

`count.keys()` : This gives you the keys or the elements present in the heap which is created using the `collections.counter`

`key = count.get()` : This is used to print the Keys of the heap. If we skip this; it will print the Values of the dictionary i.e. the number of times the element is occurring in the dictionary.